# How to log MDC while using filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I am using filter for MDC logging to print the attributes in all layers(controller and service) but I was only able to print them in filter(MyHandlerInterceptor) only below is code I am using.

can anyone please help me with this how to get the attributes in all layers where we using logger message.

=================================================================
The code below is setting them before the request has been handled and I was unable to pull the data here.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

@Component
public class MyHandlerInterceptor implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyHandlerInterceptor.class);

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public MyHandlerInterceptor(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);

        Map<String, Object> pathParams = (Map<String, Object>) wrappedRequest
                .getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);

        Map<String, Object> treeMapOfParam = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

        if(pathParams!=null){
            treeMapOfParam.putAll(pathParams);
        }

        String body = new String(wrappedRequest.getContentAsByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Map<String, Object> objectBody = !body.isEmpty() ? objectMapper.readValue(body, Map.class) : new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, Object> treeMapOfBody = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        treeMapOfBody.putAll(objectBody);
        try {


                if (HttpMethod.POST.toString().equals(wrappedRequest.getMethod())) {


                    MDC.put("ID", treeMapOfBody.containsKey("ID") ? treeMapOfBody.get("ID").toString() : null);
                   System.out.println(treeMapOfBody.get("ID"));
                    logger.info("hellopost");

                } else if (HttpMethod.GET.toString().equals(wrappedRequest.getMethod())
                        && treeMapOfParam.containsKey("ID")) {

                    MDC.put("ID", treeMapOfParam.get("ID").toString());
                    logger.info("helloget");

                }

            filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, servletResponse);
        } finally {
          MDC.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only setting them **after** the request has been handled, so anything before doesn't have the MDC set.

Comment: @M.Deinum I modifed the code setting to be done before but I am facing issue with reading the payload and I am getting empty body (But my post request has body ). Above I modified the code and updated. Any help is appreciated, thanks. – 
Karth

Comment: Because the body is only available after it has been read, it hasn't been read at that point. Which, if you read [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.html#getContentAsByteArray--) should be clear from the start. So just read it like you would do with a normal request.